# How to tell the last commit of a given git branch merged into another branch to find changes made on the branch?

Tags: git, merge, git-extensions

Suppose I have a **feature_x** git branch created from the **master** branch. I want to review the changes made on **feature_x**, in other words - what changes would be made to **master** if **feature_x** was to be merged into it now?

This is exactly what GitHub pull requests show, but I want to see the difference in Git Extensions without creating a pull request. The latest version of Git Extensions (2.49) has a very useful "compare branches" feature, which does exactly this.

The only problem is that if I compare to the latest commit on **master** this includes other changes made to **master** since it was last merged into **feature_x**. So instead of the latest commit on **master** I want to use the last commit that was merged into **feature_x** as the basis for comparison. How do can I find it, easily and reliably (preferably in Git Extensions, but a git command would do)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git diff master...feature_x
```

This will do exactly what you want, showing a diff of the changes that are in `feature_x` but not in `master`. Be aware that there are three dots intentionally. With two dots you would compare the latest `master` vs. the latest `feature_x`.

Comment: That seems to work, but it shows me a text diff for each file. I want to use the Git Extensions GUI to view the diff more easily. How do I find out which revision of master this command is comparing to?

Comment: `git merge-base master feature_x`

Comment: You can also use `git difftool` instead of `git diff`, then your external diff tool displays the diffs instead of the textual diff view. I recommend P4Merge, it is the best free diff and merge tool that I know.

Comment: Great, `merge-base` does exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Git Extensions Diff has a "Compare to merge base" checkbox, which does exactly what I want, but it wasn't obvious before, because feature_x was my BASE, so checking it didn't produce a meaningful result.

If I'm currently on the **master** branch and I select a commit on the **feature_x** branch and select **Compare, Compare with current branch** I then need to swap the branches in the Diff dialog (so **master** is the BASE) and check "Compare to merge base".

Comment: Well, you would get a meaningful result, just not the one you expected. The result are the changes that were done on master since you branced off feature_x. :-)